# What algorithm can I use to collapse a set of combinations using an asterisk to encode "all"?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I'm having some trouble finding an algorithm that can reduce a subset of the combinations of n choose k into a smaller set using * to symbolize all possible combinations that contain the other elements in the subset. It is easiest to explain using some test cases.

**For n choose k where n is 6 and k is 3**

```
//Case 1 - 1 Group
Input = [
   [1,2,3],
   [1,2,4],
   [1,2,5],
   [1,2,6]
]
Output = [[1,2,*]]

//Case 2 - 2 Groups
Input = [
   [1,2,3],
   [1,2,4],
   [1,2,5],
   [1,2,6],
   [1,3,4],
   [1,3,5],
   [1,3,6],
   [1,4,5],
   [1,4,6],
   [1,5,6]
]
Output = [[1,*,*]]

//Case 3 - 1 Group and 1 non-collapsible
Input = [
   [1,2,3],
   [1,2,4],
   [1,2,5],
   [1,2,6],
   [1,3,4]
]
Output = [[1,2,*], [1,3,4]]
```

Since these are combinations, the output is order insensitive. `[1,2,*]` and `[1,*,2]` are considered equal.

It also means that each number can only be used once in the output. `[1,1,2]` would be invalid.

Another way of thinking about the meaning of the output would be that `[1,*,*]` means "every single combination that contains a 1" and `[1,2,*]` would mean "every single combination that contains a 1 and 2"

Comment: Hi. Can you explain why Case 3 does not result in `Output = [[1,*,*]]`?

Comment: @stef Missing triplets like [1,4,5]???

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès But in that case, why is `[1,2,*]` part of the output, even though there is no triplet `[1,2,1]` or `[1,2,2]`?

Comment: @Stef in n choose k each number can only be used once, [1,2,1] is not valid because 1 cannot be used twice

Comment: @Jacob Okay. Is it possible to have something like `[1,*,5]` in the output for some case, and if yes can you provide such an example case, or can the stars only be at the end of the combination?

Comment: Anyway, looking at each position, in the triplet, starting from the leftmost position, I would check which of these three situations we are in: (a) All elements are equal at this position; (b) All possible values exist at this position; (c) More than one, but less than all, values exist at this position. Then if you're in case (a), you can write the value at this position in the output; if you're in case (b), you can write a star at this position in the output; if you're in case (c), split the triplets in groups by value, and use recursion to generate the output for each group.

Comment: (I would have posted my previous comment earlier but it's still unclear to me what is the exact meaning of "all possible values" given the fact that triplets represent combinations; and I suspect that it might not be entirely clear to you too, and it needs to be clarified in order to write the exact algorithm)

Comment: @Stef combinations are order-insensitive `[1,*,5]` and `[*,1,5]` are equal. Another way of clarifying the meaning would be that `[1,*,*]` means "every single combination that contains a 1" and `[1,2,*]` would mean "every single combination that contains a 1 and 2"

Comment: @Jacob Okay. Maybe a slight modification of what I wrote above, then. For each possible element k starting from k=1, check which of these three situations we are in: (a) All combinations have k; (b) Not all combinations have k, but all values between k and n exist; (c) More than one, but less than all, values between k and n exist. Then do the split as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: Well, as often happens on StackOverflow, I finished writing my answer about 30seconds after the question was closed and so I cannot click the "Post your answer" button.

Comment: @Jacob I voted to reopen. In the meantime you can read my answer: https://pastebin.com/HPzRMNCU

Comment: I suggest editing the question to add the clarifications that you wrote in comments, and checking the "This edit resolves the reasons why the question was closed" checkbox before submitting the edit.

Comment: Well, the code I wrote correctly answers `Case 1:  [(1, 2, '*')], Case 2:  [(1, '*', '*')], Case 3:  [(1, 2, '*'), (1, 3, 4)]` on your three testcases, and I also tried it with `n=5,k=3, case4 = [[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5]]`, and it successfully returned `[(1, '*', 5)]`. However for `n=6,k=3, case5 = [[1,2,5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [1, 6, 5]]` it answers `[(1, '*', 5), (1, '*', 6)]`, which might or might not be what you want.

Comment: Reminds one of optimizing logical expressions (with the practical application of reducing number of transistors/gates needed). This field has some theory and algorithms and also visual/manual procedures of doing it.

Comment: @Sebastian If you know how to reduce bitwise expressions as well, the asker of that question will be interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77931619/can-combination-of-multiplication-addition-or-xor-not-induce-permutation/77931829#77931829

Comment: @Stef I have updated the question to include the clarifications I made in the comments. For your latest example the [1,*,6] would be an invalid output as the input does not contain all combinations containing a 1 and 6. I did manage to put together my own solution (though it might not be very optimal) which I will post if the question gets reopened